# Goal specific javax.net.ssl.trustStore

Tags: maven, ssl

I've got a Maven project for which i use org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat6-maven-plugin to deploy to a remote Tomcat.

This tomcat is configured so that i need to specify:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=mykeystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=mypassword
```

My problem is that by doing so, I can't download dependencies anymore from remote repositories through my company proxy as it tries to establish a secure connection using this truststore and it fails...

I'm looking for a way to connect to both ends (maven repo and my remote tomcat) without having to set/unset my MAVEN_OPTS variable every time...
I've seen that I can have a `<configuration />` element in my settings.xml, but I can't find what to put in it.

Thanks...

Comment: Have you try with different maven profiles??? you can use one for downloading and working as usual and one special profile for deploy the application into the tomcat server

Comment: I've heard about profiles but I don't know yet how to use it... I'll give it a look, but if you have some example I'll take it... ;)

Comment: I'll add an answer with that...

Comment: My IDE being Inetllij at the moment, i solved my problem by setting several "Run Configurations" for tomcat related goals with the appropriate VM Options...

Answer (score 1):

Using different profiles with maven:
Define the active profiles in your pom (you can also define profiles in settings.xml but I think this should work for your case):

```
<profiles>

    <profile>
        <id>TOMCAT_DEPLOY</id>
        <activation>
            // Rules to active the profile
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>

        <properties>
        </properties>
        // Add rest of profile specific configuration
   </profile>
</profiles>
```

For executing maven with an specific profile, basically you have a list of active profiles and you can execute one of them according to different triggers:

A profile can be triggered/activated in several ways:

Explicitly, Through Maven settings, Based on environment variables OS settings or based on some Present or missing files

Please, read this [link](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) where you can have all information about profiles and how activate them for any execution

Comment: thanks for your answer but even with profiles I can't figure how to define such property as `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=mykeystore.jks`...

Comment: Could you edit the question and show your maven configuration or at least the part where you set that variables??